# How do I generate a reference to a user name given the id with sql alchemy Flask?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a post model like so:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    contents = db.Column(db.String(700))
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    author_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __init__(self, title, contents, author_id):
        self.title = title
        self.contents = contents
        self.author_id = author_id
        self.time = datetime.now()
```

My users can change their name whenever they like. I don't want to have to keep updating the author_name variable because that would be redundant. When I already have the id. How do I get it so that when I reference author_name, it just fetches me the User.query.get(author_id).name?

I don't want to simply use User.query.get(author_id).name because I have to use it in a jinja2 template. I cannot fetch things from User so I'd like it to be kept with each post.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to start by defining a relationship between your Post class and your User class. I'm guessing a 'one-to-many' relationship where a User can have many Posts, but a post can only have 1 User (or Author).
To do this redefine the `author_id` as a Foreign Key referencing the User class (or Author class if that's what you have), instead as just an Integer (like you currently have).

Then you can define an `author` attribute (not a column) to the Post class that holds a reference to the Post's author. This will allow you to get the author's name from a Post via `post.author.name`.

```
class Post(db.Model):
  author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id'), nullable=False)
  author = db.relationship(lambda: User, uselist=False)
  .
  .
  .
```

Now you can get the author's name with:

```
post.author.name
```

If instead you wanted to reference the author's name like this instead `post.author_name` you could leverage an [association proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html)

```
class Post(db.Model):
  author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id'), nullable=False)
  author = db.relationship(lambda: User, uselist=False)
  author_name = association_proxy('author', 'name')
  .
  .
  .
```

Now you can get the author's name with

```
post.author_name
```